# Not cookie based session management in node.js

Tags: node.js, session

I am looking for a non-cookie based session management in node.js, something like pass a parameter in the URL like `&session_id=`. It will know that a session has expired when a request comes with an session_id. I've looked at `connect` library, but it looks that it is cookie based only.

Comment: I've never come across such a module. It's also doubtful it exists, since it requires support from the templating engine as well (to inject the session id into every link). So I think you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

#### Warning

Passing the `session id` as a GET parameter is considered bad practice. Why? It is dangerous because people don't usually care about `session id` and they will probably publish/share links with their session ids inside.

It's also a problem because when a user clicks an external link on your web, and goes to another site, that new site will be able to see the `session_id` in the referrer link.

So I don't think it is a good idea. Cookies are more secure.

Have a look at: [Session Hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking)

Comment: This is not for a public website. And the client is not necessarily cookie enabled. Anyway, your warning makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For every request you receive, you will get all of the client cookies accordingly.
You can also set client cookies in the response HTTP headers using "Set-Cookie."

Using a GET parameter is unsafe. Any user could accidently share their session ID, but if you want 100% security, I'd share session IDs via cookies, and I would use HTTPS to prevent snoopers from stealing cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localstorage` or `sessionStorage`..

- almost same as cookie
- not a cookie
- better than a cookie!

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

It's very -*very*- easy to use... in Js for example:

```
<script>
    // check if Storage is avaible
  if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
    // Save data to local storage (no exiparion date)
    localStorage.setItem("name_always", "bxx");
    // Save data to the current session (removes when the tab is closed)
    sessionStorage.setItem("name_now", "bxx");
  } else {
    // No Storage support...
  }
  // Access to stored data
  alert( "For only now, my name is: " + sessionStorage.getItem("name_now"));
  alert( "Every day, my name is: " + localStorage.getItem("name_always"));
</script>
```

Tags: [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) [local-storage](/questions/tagged/local-storage) [session-storage](/questions/tagged/session-storage)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions with a store in node.js. For example, you have express application and want to use session like system in your webapp. You can use [connect-mongo](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-mongo) module for this. This will let you store your session in db. In your app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    , mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);

var app = express();

app.configure('all', function () {
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: "terces",
        cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
        store: new mongoStore({
            url: your_db_url
        })
    }));
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.locals.session = req.session;
        next();
    });
});
```

With basic code above, you have session in express that you can use it in your controllers and views directly. In your controller;

```
app.post('/blog/create/?', function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        next("You need to login in order to create blog!");
    }
});
```

In your view, you can use `session.user` in order to generate profile menu for example.